# How to determine size of data added in one second in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList where data are added dynamically.

```
ArrayList<Double> al = new ArrayList<Double>();
while ( data !=null ){
  al.add(data);
}
```

Question are
1.how to get the size of data added in one second?
2.is it ok to use ArrayList if data are added in real-time?
So, i tried without real data by replacing with randomly generated data. this is what i have done so far.

```
static long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
static double sec = 5;
static double ans;
static double whenToEnd = 30;
static int i = 0;
int ii = 1;
static ArrayList<Double> al = new ArrayList<Double>();
private static int DataLengthIn1s;
static int previousLength = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < whenToEnd * 1000) {

        writeData();

        System.out.println("Current size of al: " + al.size());
    }

    System.out.println("Total size of al: " + al.size());

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long totalTime = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println("Total process time: " + totalTime);
}


public static void writeData() {
    long innerStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - innerStartTime) < sec * 1000) {
        ans = getRandom();
        al.add(i, ans);
        getDataLengthIn1s(innerStartTime);
        i++;
    }
}

private static int getDataLengthIn1s(long innerStartTime) {
    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() + innerStartTime) == 1000) {
        int length = al.size() - previousLength;
        System.out.println("In one second, data added are: " + length);
        previousLength = al.size();
    }
    return 0;
}

private static double getRandom() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    double lower = 0;
    double upper = 1;

    double result = Math.random() * (upper - lower) + lower;
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;

}
```

in this code, i get 600 data for 30 seconds. means, 600/30=20 data/s . but for real implementation, the data sent for one seconds will not going to be same all the time. Another reason is so i can delete the previous data by knowing the size of currently added data.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

> how to get the size of data added in one second?

If you wonder how many items have been added to a list in the last second, then you can check how many items are currently in the list, wait a second, and then check again how many items are in the list. However, note that this measurement will not be exact as waiting times are subject to the scheduler.

In the following snippet, a thread checks every seconds how many items have been added to the list in the last second:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class ListPerformance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean(false);
        final List<Double> queue = new ArrayList<Double>();
        Thread producer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (!stop.get()) {
                    queue.add(Math.random());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(Math.round(Math.random() * 10));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        Thread timer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (!stop.get()) {
                    int startingSize = queue.size();
                    long startingTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Added " + (queue.size() - startingSize) + " items in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startingTime) + " ms");
                }
            }
        });
        producer.start();
        timer.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stop.set(true);
    }
}
```

The result can be something like:

```
Added 190 items in 1000 ms
Added 193 items in 1000 ms
Added 208 items in 1000 ms
Added 200 items in 1000 ms
...
```

Note that the list is shared between the two threads. If you want to, say, delete items from the list in one thread and add items in a second thread, then you absolutely must lock the list, e.g., `synchronized(queue){...`, in both, the producing and the consuming thread. Most likely there also exist numerous optimized thread-safe list implementations.

I am not sure what your ultimate goal is, but you may also consider creating a new list about every second (I'd tie it to an amount of data rather than time) and have multiple independent collections of data instead of one huge collection. That way, you can throw away entire lists that you don't need instead of modifying your sole list.

> is it ok to use ArrayList if data are added in real-time?

If you're talking about a true real-time system, then I don't think the list implementation is what you should be concerned about. More critical is the scheduling of the threads and garbage collection. I can't tell you how to implement a real-time system, but you may want to have a look at the [Real Time Garbage Collector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/realtime/doc_2.1/release/JavaRTSGarbageCollection.html#mozTocId860663) if you consider using Java.

If you're not talking about true real-time, but simply want to know if there are better collections for you to use, then - based on your description - you may want to search for *Java Buffer*, or *Java Queue* and decide whether you find something appropriate to your specific use case.